# Condition expression - how to get REPORT TYPE in condition Expression

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I would like to write expression like this:

```
{REPORT_TYPE} == "csv" ? "'" + $F{NUMBER_VALUE} : $F{NUMBER_VALUE}
```

where {REPORT_TYPE} should be xls, csv etc.

Have you any idea how to get report type?

Comment: Could you not simply pass the output type as a report parameter?

Comment: @DavidSilva `report type` - About what application are you talking? It can be custom *Java* application or it can be *JR Server*, for example

Comment: Is this report type upon export?

Comment: I was looking for built-in parameter to get report type, but sadly I suppose it doesn't exist. Am I right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to send a parameter from your server which will get these type of format like `csv`,`xls`. If this parameter has some value then you can use this expression. e.g. you have a parameter named reportType then you can make a syntax like this.

```
$P{reportType} ? "'" + $F{NUMBER_VALUE} : $F{NUMBER_VALUE}
```

if you want report type like csv then you need to give a value to this parameter, otherwise send it as blank string.

If you still get problem let me know.